# search with an array associate with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to do a search  by name and surname with an array javascript, and the results in a div. for example: I write Ali in input, an it shoul show me Alison and Alibaba.
this is my code, but it's giving errors; are there other ways to do it?:

```
<input type='text' id='filter' placeholder='search'>
<div id='output' style='margin-top:50px '></div>
```

my array

```
var arrayD =[
    {"Name":"Alison","Surname":"Kenn","Mobile":529129293},
    {"Name":"Ashton","Surname":"Jhojan","Mobile":529129293},
    {"Name":"Bith","Surname":"Klint","Mobile":129129293},
    {"Name":"Ana","Surname":"Clow","Mobile":229129293},
    {"Name":"Geoge","Surname":"Rich","Mobile":329129293},
    {"Name":"kenneth","Surname":"Cooler","Mobile":329129}
]

var $result = $('#output');
$('#filter').on('keyup', function () {
    var $fragment = $('<div />');
    var val = this.value.toLowerCase();
    $.each(arrayD, function (i, item) {
        console.log( item[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(val));
        if ( item[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(val) == 0 ) {
            $fragment.append('<li>' + item[0] + ' ' + item[1] + '</li>');
        }
    });
    $result.html( $fragment.children() );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/henrykend/ChpgZ/4/

Comment: where is `#filter` element ? and why are you using `html()` method over an `input` element?

Comment: filter is input type='text'

Comment: so you need to also update the fiddle with your actual code

Comment: Why not just fix the errors it's giving you?

Comment: @Fabrizio Calderan yeah, but doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you're trying to reference fields in the object by ordinal position rather than name. There is nothing automagic in JavaScript which will read `item.Name` (or `item["Name"]`) from `item[0]`.

There is also no need to build up a "false element" (in your case `$fragment`) and then append its children to the output area - you may as well do this in one go (remembering to `.empty()` it between calls).

Your corrected code:

```
var $result = $('#result');
$('#output').on('keyup', function () {
    $result.empty();
    var val = this.value.toLowerCase();
    $.each(arrayD, function (i, item) {
        if ( item.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) == 0 ) {
            $result.append('<li>' + item.Name + ' ' + item.Surname + '</li>');
        }
    });
});
```

And a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ChpgZ/6/

Comment: @chikatetsu - great, glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

You had couple of problems in your code.

1. Names of the elements we're wrongly placed (which you've fixed with the edit)
2. In the .each, you've used item[0] instead of item.Name (also surname)

See the following code

```
var arrayD =[
    {"Name":"Alison","Surname":"Kenn","Mobile":529129293},
    {"Name":"Ashton","Surname":"Jhojan","Mobile":529129293},
    {"Name":"Bith","Surname":"Klint","Mobile":129129293},
    {"Name":"Ana","Surname":"Clow","Mobile":229129293},
    {"Name":"Geoge","Surname":"Rich","Mobile":329129293},
    {"Name":"kenneth","Surname":"Cooler","Mobile":329129}
]
var $result = $('#result');
$('#output').on('keyup', function () {
    var $fragment = $('<div />');
    var val = this.value.toLowerCase();
    $.each(arrayD, function (i, item) {console.log( item.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) );
        if ( item.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) == 0 ) {
            $fragment.append('<li>' + item.Name + ' ' + item.Surname + '</li>');
        }
    });
    $result.html( $fragment.children() );
});
```